# Codeigniter url issues for product pages

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a Codeigniter website where I have an issue that, all  my product urls having 2 different urls.
I only want a single url for each product.

```
Like for a product:

https://www.bentleypartsusa.com/category/products_listing/138/
https://www.bentleypartsusa.com/category/products_listing/138/pg/
```

There are two urls for each product. So how I can solve this problem.

This is my htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on
    
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.bentleypartsusa.com/$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/home$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]

    Redirect /home/car-red/feed/ https://www.bentleypartsusa.com/
    Redirect /members/wishlist.html https://www.bentleypartsusa.com/
    Redirect /pages/download_document/document/dumymy_pdf2.pdf https://www.bentleypartsusa.com/
    Redirect /captcha/normal/15208659655aa692ad4f997 https://www.bentleypartsusa.com/
    Redirect /captcha/normal/15653168405d4cd6e827d9e https://www.bentleypartsusa.com/
    Redirect /captcha/normal/15286640755b1d900b1e51a https://www.bentleypartsusa.com/
    
    # Keep people out of codeigniter directory and Git/Mercurial data
    RedirectMatch 403 ^/(system\/cms\/cache|system\/codeigniter|\.git|\.hg).*$

    # Send request via index.php (again, not if its a real file or folder)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Any help is really appreciated

TIA

Comment: Please show your code first

Comment: What routes do you use? Also do you use maybe pagination or whats the /pg?

Comment: Please check now added .htaccess file code

Comment: where is the problem, which of the 2 urls above do you want? look at this (your) question, the url is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64425537/codeigniter-url-issues-for-product-pages, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64425537 also works, adding the slug part automatically

Comment: I want to remove /pg from slug

Comment: Please show the controller code and routes code